# ITextRenderer.setDocumentFromString(html) is causing javax.xml.transform.TransformerException

Tags: java, html, xml, pdf, flying-saucer

I am transforming some HTML with `JSoup`. After the final HTML is produced I want to render it into pdf file. For that I am using `Flying saucer` libraries.

Html example I am trying to render:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
<title></title> 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /> 
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" /> 
...
```

Method for rendering the html to pdf:

```
private void createPdfFile(String html, String fileName) throws IOException, DocumentException {
    ITextRenderer renderer = new ITextRenderer();

    renderer.setDocumentFromString(html);
    renderer.layout();

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(fileName);
    renderer.createPDF( fos );
    fos.close();
    System.out.println( "File 2: '" + fileName + "' created." );
    }
```

Error log:

```
org.xhtmlrenderer.util.XRRuntimeException: Can't load the XML resource (using TRaX transformer). org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 64; The system identifier must begin with either a single or double quote character.
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:191)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource.load(XMLResource.java:75)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.pdf.ITextRenderer.setDocumentFromString(ITextRenderer.java:157)
    at main.Main.createPdfFile(Main.java:106)
    at main.Main.getEmailAsset(Main.java:97)
    at main.ServletMain.doGet(ServletMain.java:52)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 64; The system identifier must begin with either a single or double quote character.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transform(Unknown Source)
    at org.xhtmlrenderer.resource.XMLResource$XMLResourceBuilder.createXMLResource(XMLResource.java:189)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 64; The system identifier must begin with either a single or double quote character.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl.transformIdentity(Unknown Source)
    ... 30 more
```

Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: remove the first line from your html and try again please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to wrap your DTD URI in quotes - you're currently unbalanced:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
```

In your existing code, you're missing the `"` before `http://www.w3...`

Comment: Thanks, but how is it possible that happened? Is there a  way to fix it with JSoup so if there are other errors like that it would be checked? Probably not, but worth asking.

Comment: No idea, I've never used it.

Comment: I am having similar issue with second line. Would you mind helping me? I will be happy to vote up. Error: `lineNumber: 2; columnNumber: 15; Element type "html" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>"`

Comment: Try running the doc through the [w3 validator](http://validator.w3.org/check) and see what  you get.

Comment: I found the issue, for some reason the Jsoup is adding additional double quotes right after equals sign.

Comment: Is there anyway I can handle <br> tag?

Answer (score 0):

check you quotation marks in the tag attributes. I didn't have a " mark and that was causing a similar error for me.